# How to solve the variable length differ error

Tags: r, lm

First post here. I am trying to create a linear regression with R by regressing each variable in the dataset with INFLATION.

```
for(i in 1:4) {             
  predictors_i <- colnames(data.all.inflation)[i+1]   
  summary(lm(predictors_i ~ data.all.inflation$INFLATION))
}
```

After running the code, the following error message appears:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = predictors_i ~ data.all.inflation$INFLATION, : variable lengths differ (found for 'data.all.inflation$INFLATION')

Please let me know if there are any more details that you want/need.Thanks!

Comment: When `i=2`, `colnames(data.all.inflation)[2:(i+1)]` will extract the second and third columns. You cannot set 2 columns as response variables in `lm()`.

Comment: `for(i in 1:2) {
  predictors_i <- colnames(data.all.inflation)[i+1]
  summary(lm(as.formula(paste(predictors_i, '~ INFLATION')), data.all.inflation))
}`

Comment: I think that is one of the errors. but after facing that error, it still shows the same error.

Comment: Hi, it runs without error but it doesnt show the summary output either.

Comment: You could store the output of each iteration into a list.

Comment: alright, I think I was able to solve it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Alternate solution: do it with library(fixest). Then feols(c(varname1, varname2, varname3, varname4) ~ INFLATION, data = data.all.inflation) will run them all for you at once (fill in varname1, etc. with the appropriate variable names).